# Conditioning a $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra state with infinite precision

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

*This question (and a second part) have been [asked at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4718733/an-infinitely-conditioned-state-in-a-c-algebra) and gone through two bounties without an answer. I have been beating my head at it for a while without success*.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra. Let $f\in \mathcal{A}$ self-adjoint with spectrum $\sigma(f)$. The bidual $\mathcal{A}^{**}$ contains the spectral projections of $f$, denoted $\mathbf{1}_{E}(f)$, for Borel $E\subseteq \sigma(f)$. Let $\lambda\in\sigma(f)$, $\varepsilon>0$ and define
$$p_\varepsilon:=\mathbf{1}_{(\lambda-\varepsilon,\lambda+\varepsilon)}(f).$$

Suppose that $\varphi$ is a state on $\mathcal{A}$, with an extension to a state on $\mathcal{A}^{**}$ denoted $\omega_\varphi$. Suppose further, and this is to be a key assumption, that for all $\varepsilon>0$, $$\omega_\varphi(p_\varepsilon)>0\qquad(\star).$$

If the following is defined, it defines a state. But is it well-defined?

**Question: Let $g\in\mathcal{A}$. Under the assumption $(\star)$, does the following limit exist:**

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\frac{\omega_\varphi(p_\varepsilon\,g\,p_\varepsilon)}{\omega_\varphi(p_\varepsilon)}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this limit doesn't exist in general. Here's a commutative counterexample.

Let $A = L^\infty[0,1]$, $f(x) = x$, $\phi =$ integration against Lebesgue measure. Let $g$ be the indicator function of the set $\bigcup [10^{-(2n + 1)}, 10^{-2n}] = [.1, 1] \cup [.001, .01] \cup [.00001, .001] \cup \cdots$.

Taking $\lambda = 0$, we get that $p_\epsilon$ is the indicator function of $[0,\epsilon]$. Then $\frac{\phi(p_\epsilon g)}{\phi(p_\epsilon)}$ takes the same value on $\epsilon =$ any even negative power of 10, and the same value on $\epsilon =$ any odd negative power of 10, and those two values aren't the same.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding to this answer: thank you. I was about to write that my thinking of $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebras as $C(X)$ was letting me down... but of course the real deficiency here is around what kind of beast $X$ can be. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! My first thought was that it would have a positive answer. Surprising to see that there was a commutative counterexample ...

Comment: Morally this example seems to reflect that $f\mapsto f(0)$ is well-defined in $C([0,1])$ but not in $L^\infty([0,1])$. Presumably in $\mathcal{A}=C([0,1])$ the limit is just $f\mapsto f(0)$.