# Is there a notion of point in noncommutative geometry?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry

It is not clear to me whether there is a general notion of *point* in NCG. I have heard (more through physics) that the notion of a point becomes meaningless or ill-defined in noncommutative spaces, but I have also learned that a point in a noncommutative algebra $A$ is a pure state on $A$. What are the obstacles or difficulties in defining such a notion? Can anyone enlighten me? Any insight is welcome

Comment: In non-commutative projective algebraic geometry, a la Artin-Schelter-Tate-van den Bergh etc, there is absolutely no obstacle or difficulty in the definition. See e.g.  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.3065.pdf, Lecture 3: Point modules.

Comment: @Balazs what is the relation between "point MODULES" and  max/prime ideals (~ Irreps) which are  analougs of "points" as discussed in many less modern sources ?

Comment: I thought that one of the main motivations in operator-algebraic NCG was to deal with "spaces" that do NOT have points - see the motivating examples in Connes's book, for instance, given by crossed products of group actions on topological spaces.

Comment: As for pure states: the pure state space of a Cstar algebra turns out to not be a good analogue of "the noncommutative topological space corresponding to the Cstar algebra" - it is a perfectly well-defined locally compact Hausdorff space, but it is somehow too big unless your Cstar algebra is close to being commutative. Where have you "learned that a point in a noncommutative algebra $A$ is a pure state on $A$"?

Comment: BTW, could you please clarify if you are mainly interested in operator-algebraic NCG, or if you are also asking about the algebraic-geometry version of NCG

Comment: @YemonChoi do not know what is the source for OP - but - seems many textbook like Faddeev-Yakubovski (if remember correctly) - write something like that - in classical mechanis one can consider MEASURES on the phase/config spaces - the delta-funtction measures - are clearly "points. Now measures - are clearly anoulogous of Tr( \mu A ) - trace functionals in non-commuative space, then you can try to define something like "pure" states by analogy - an in some sense say that these are "points". I have seen it many times - but never found a clear discussion - so any one who can clarify - welcome !

Comment: @AlexanderChervov Sure, one does deal with pure states on Cstar algebras, and it is a theorem that for a commutative Cstar algebra the pure states correspond to the points of the Gelfand spectrum. But as I said above, for general noncommutative Cstar algebras the space of pure states space is too big, unless you quotient by some group action on it, and then the resulting space is usually singular (non-Hausdorff) and wild (not Borel classifiable)

Comment: @YemonChoi thanks for your comment ! But if the think of the example Cstar which is quantization of commuative manifold - what  are expected to be these "pure states" ? "How many of them" we expect to have  ? What are their "classical" limits ?

Comment: @AlexanderChervov That's a good example. I **think** that one still has problems for the irrational rotation algebras / noncommutative tori, because these Cstar algebras are not "Type I" and so it is known that the pure state space is very large (and its quotient, the space of irreducible representations equipped with Fell's topology, is very badly behaved). Part of the NCG revolution in operator algebras was to use invariants such as K-theory to say things about the global structure of "noncommutative spaces" without needing to identify the "points" of these spaces.

Comment: @YemonChoi thanks for the comment ! is something discussed about "classical limits" of pure states for some algebras which are thought to be quantization of commutative manifolds ? (I am not sure that question is strictly well-defined since  typically quantization is formal deformation over "h" , not Cstar , but it seems there are ways to make Cstar at least what I remember from Landsmans talks ). Any way there can be informal anologies even if it is not very formal

Comment: @AlexanderChervov For a commutative unital ring $R$, there is a one-to-one correspondence between ideals $I\lhd R$ and cyclic $R$-modules $R/I$. If you take this point of view, in the graded case the Hilbert function has a simpler expression.

Comment: @Balazs thanks for your comment . I have a question for years - consider standard Heisenberg (= Weyl) [x,y]=1 , there are results by Cannings-Holland, Wilson-Berest which describe certain modules  are parameterized points in C^2 - so  kind of commutive limits of Heisenberg - Spec(C[x,y]). Are these modules "point modules" in the sense of your reference ?  That would be the way to see classical Spec(C[x,y]) from quantum algebra

Comment: @YemonChoi I am more talking about operator-algebraic and differential NCG. In fact, my first interests were on quantum gravity/spacetime (and algebraic QFT)

Comment: @AlexanderChervov no, they are not. Note that from the point of view of my comment, the Weyl algebra is affine, not projective; it's a noncommutative deformation of ${\mathbb A}^2$, not of ${\mathbb P}^2$. It has no finite-dimensional quotients, so no points...

Comment: ...In the context of my remark, you would have to homogenise first, as you would do in standard commutative algebraic geometry, to get the equation $[x,y]=z^2$ in three variables. Now you have a graded non-commutative algebra, with all the right conditions so that the Artin et al theory applies. And in this case, all point modules must have $z=0$, so ''lie at infinity'', and they are simply points on the ''classical'' ${\mathbb P}^1$ inside the noncommutative  ${\mathbb P}^2$.

Comment: @Balazs thank you for the explanations !

Comment: @Balazs would the following simple-minded way be "correct" - [x,y]=z , and z-cental - so we have lots of ideals/irreps which correspond to z = CONST - thay probaly is that commutative "A^1" in non-commuative  ?  something like that ?

Comment: In this case (and indeed $z$ central, I forgot to say this earlier), you can still only have $z=0$ for finite dimensional quotient for the affine case (or point-like Hilbert function in the projective case), for the usual reason of taking the trace (in char zero). The commutative part only exists (for point-like objects) along the line $z=0$.

Comment: @Esmond this question has had lots of relatively minor edits (21 of them in two days), each of which bump the question to the top of the current list. In case you weren't aware, this is not viewed favourably on MO.  Adding a closing sentence like " Any insight is welcome" then replacing it with "Thanks", then replacing it again with a variant on the former etc, are not clarifying edits, but purely cosmetic and are borderline abuse to keep the question on the front page. People are already engaging with your question, no need to keep pushing it up.

Comment: @DavidRoberts It's true that it was rather dishonest of me. Excuse me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A caveat: everything correct and/or good in this is stolen. I should have probably written this more carefully but given some comments above I felt too much time may have been a bad idea. I pause for a quote here from William Thurston:

> This question brings to the fore something that is fundamental and pervasive:
> that what we [mathematicians] are doing is finding ways for people to understand and think about mathematics.

Essentially the below gives an interpretation, and it is one that has served me in my area and has helped me understand and think about mathematics. However, the question is, if nobody else likes or share such an interpretation, does it comprise mathematics?

---

I will work in the setting of a unital $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$. If $\mathcal{A}$ is commutative, then we know that $\mathcal{A}=C(X)$ is the algebra of continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space $X$. This is a categorical equivalence given by Gelfand's Theorem:
$$\text{compact Hausdorff spaces}\simeq (\text{unital commutative $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebras})^{\text{op}}.$$
Starting with a compact Hausdorff space $X$, the algebra of continuous functions on $X$, $C(X)$, is a unital commutative $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra; and starting with a unital commutative $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$, its spectrum, $\Omega(\mathcal{A})$, the set of *characters*, non-zero *-homomorphisms $\mathcal{A}\to \mathbb{C}$, is a compact Hausdorff space such that $\mathcal{A}\cong C(\Omega(\mathcal{A}))$.

A first push in the general direction of your question is to consider a non-commutative unital $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra as the algebra of continuous functions on a compact *quantum* space, and a general unital commutative $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra can be denoted $\mathcal{A}=C(\mathbb{X})$. Inspired by this, one can define the category of `compact quantum spaces' as
$$\text{compact quantum spaces}:\simeq (\text{unital $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebras})^{\text{op}}.$$

One way to interpret your question is to note that a *point* in the commutative setting is an element $x\in X$, so to extend to the noncommutative setting the compact quantum space $\mathbb{X}$ must be identified with a *set*.

The most obvious and trivial obstruction to this is that in the commutative case the product on $\mathcal{A}=C(X)$ is the point-wise multiplication:
$$(fg)(x)=f(x)g(x)\qquad (f,g\in C(X),\,x\in X),$$
and the commutativity of $\mathbb{C}$ gives commutativity to this product. We cannot, in general, consider the product on noncommutative $\mathcal{A}=C(\mathbb{X})$ to be a pointwise product because the product is no longer commutative.

So, the first answer to your question is to say that there are no points, that $\mathbb{X}$ is not a set-of-points, but a *virtual object*. While we can use the $C(\mathbb{X})$ to help with intuition, making definitions, etc., it is futile to ask your question. We will use this notation from now on, $C(\mathbb{X})$ is a not-necessarily commutative unital $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra. This might be called the *Gelfand Philosophy*.

---

Now the question is: could we interpret $\mathbb{X}$ as a set...

My first attempt to do this went something like this (I won't explain fully, but at some point was inspired by the text Nik mentioned (I remember something like... *a self-adjoint operator is like a labelling of eigenspaces*)): suppose $C(\mathbb{X})\subseteq B(\mathsf{H})$ for a Hilbert space $\mathsf{H}$. Let self-adjoint $f\in C(\mathbb{X})$ be of finite spectrum (if you are interested in measuring something that is not of finite spectrum, partition its spectrum into finitely many Borel subsets, and use Borel functional calculus in $C(\mathbb{X})''$ to get something finite spectrum). What does $f$ 'see' when it looks at $\mathsf{H}$? It sees a finite set: the set of eigenspaces $X_f:=\{E_\lambda\,|\,\lambda\in\sigma(f)\}$, and $f$ is like a function $X_f\to \mathbb{C}$, $f(E_\lambda)=\lambda$. If you take a different finite-spectrum self-adjoint $g\in C(\mathbb{G})$, $g$ *also* sees a set, $X_g$, but if $f$ and $g$ don't commute,  then $f$ and $g$ don't agree on the set that they see, and so we don't get a self-adjoint $fg$. If $f$ and $g$ *do* commute, they will agree what set they see, $X_f=X_g$, and it will make sense to consider $fg:X_f\to \mathbb{C}$. So the Hilbert space is the quantum space, and the manifestation of the quantumness is that what set it is depends on what observable is looking at it. That is a first pass. I got into all kinds of problems around unitary equivalence, etc., and abandoned this.

---

My second attempt went like this. Start with $C(X)$ with $X$ a classical space.

1. Each self-adjoint $f\in C(X)$ is a real-valued function: input $x$, output $f(x)$.
2. $X$ is compact Hausdorff.
3. Each such $f$ is continuous: $\lim_\lambda f(x_\lambda)=f(\lim_\lambda x_\lambda)$.
4. If we consider $X$ as a set of "states", we can use elements of $C(X)$ to learn more and more about the state, and we can measure away without affecting the state.

Next consider the actual state space $\mathcal{S}(C(X))$, which consists via integration of regular Borel measures on $X$. Let us look naively at this, at $C(X)\sim C(\mathcal{S}(A))$:

1. Each self-adjoint $f\in C(X)$ is a real valued function: input $\nu\in \mathcal{S}(C(X))$, output $\nu(f)$. Using the isometric embedding into the bidual $\imath:C(X)\hookrightarrow C(X)^{**}$, we could write this as input $\nu$, output $\imath(f)(\nu)$... to share the "$f(x)$" form of notation.
2. $\mathcal{S}(C(X))$ is compact Hausdorff.
3. Each such $f$ is continuous with respect to the weak*-topology:
   $$\lim_\lambda\imath(f)(\nu_\lambda)=\imath(f)\left(\lim_\lambda \nu_\lambda\right)$$

But when we consider point 4, we get into bother, because 1 above is wrong. We are working in probability here: $\nu$ is an expectation:
$$\nu(f)=\mathbb{E}_\nu[f]\qquad (f\in C(X)).$$
Next I argue that we cannot in general measure with infinite precision (relevant: [Conditioning a $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra state with infinite precision](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450349/conditioning-a-mathrmc-algebra-state-with-infinite-precision)), so we must consider finite spectrum $f$ (which might place $f\in C(\mathbb{X})^{**}$ via some Borel functional calculus, in which case $p_\lambda$ will be some $\mathbf{1}_{B_\lambda}(f)$ with the $B_\lambda$ forming a partition of $\sigma(f)$ into Borel sets). So in fact, we should have something like:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f&=\sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(f)}\lambda\,p_\lambda
\\ \implies \nu(f)&=\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma(f)}\lambda\,\nu(p_\lambda),
\end{aligned}
$$
and so if $\nu$ is an expectation, in fact:

$$\mathbb{E}_\nu(f)=\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma(f)}\lambda\,\nu(p_\lambda)\implies\mathbb{P}_\nu[f=\lambda]=\nu(p_\lambda).$$

This is just classical probability, $p_\lambda$ is just the indicator function
$$p_\lambda=\mathbf{1}_{\{x\in X\,\colon\,f(x)=\lambda\}}.$$
but of course given a state $\nu$, when we measure a random variable $f\in C(X)$, and find $f=\lambda$ we have a conditioning, and you can see that it is given as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\nu&\mapsto \widetilde{p_\lambda}\nu, \qquad\text{ where}
\\\widetilde{p_\lambda}\nu(f)&=\frac{\nu(p_\lambda fp_\lambda)}{\nu(p_\lambda)}\qquad (f\in C(X))
\end{aligned}
$$
This is just classical probability theory, and the 1-4. get replaced by:

1. Each self-adjoint $f\in C(X)$ is a real-valued random variable function: given a state $\nu\in\mathcal{S}(C(X))$, output $f=\lambda$ occurs with probability $\nu(p_\lambda)$, and $\mathbb{E}_\nu(f)=\nu(f)$.
2. $\mathcal{S}(C(X))$ is compact Hausdorff.
3. Each such $f$ is continuous as a function $\mathcal{S}(C(X))\to \mathbb{C}$: $$\lim_\lambda f(\nu_\lambda)=f(\lim_\lambda \nu_\lambda).$$
4. If we consider $\mathcal{S}(C(X))$ as a set of "states", we can use elements of $C(X)$ to learn more and more about the state, but measurement involves state conditioning.

So I want us to make a jump here from $C(X)$ with points $x\in X$ to $C(X)$ with points $\nu\in \mathcal{S}(C(X))$. Now... why is this a cogent leap? I quote from https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S072308692100075X (note $M_p(G)$ via integration is the same as the state space):

> This *Gelfand-Birkhoff* picture requires a  leap to be made before ever 'going quantum'. Pick up a fresh deck of $N$ cards in some known order and "randomly" shuffle the deck. The shuffle is distributed according to some probability $\nu$ in the set of probabilities on $S_{N}$, $M_p(S_N)$. Without turning over the cards, i.e. without making measurements, it can not be said exactly what permutation acted on the deck. The leap here is to not just consider as permutations the *deterministic permutations* in $S_N$, but also the *random permutations* in $M_p(S_N)$ (which includes via the Dirac measures the deterministic permutations). Bilinearly extending the group law to $M_p(S_N)$, gives the *random group law*, the convolution
> $$(\mu\star \nu)(\{\sigma\})=\sum_{\tau\in S_N}\mu(\{\sigma\tau^{-1}\})\nu(\{\tau\})\qquad\qquad(\mu,\,\nu\in M_p(S_N)).$$ The Dirac measure concentrated at the identity is an identity for the random group law. Furthermore the inverse can be extended to a map $\operatorname{inv}:M_p(S_N)\to M_p(S_N)$, which gives the inverse of a Dirac measure for the random group law. Precisely because the map $\operatorname{inv}$ is not an inverse on the whole of $M_p(S_N)$, the set of random permutations   does not form a group, but it is nonetheless a monoid whose elements can be well-interpreted, understood, and studied in their own right. Note that where $C(S_N)$ is the algebra of complex-valued functions on $S_N$, $M_p(S_N)$ is the subset of positive functionals of norm one on $C(S_N)$: the set of *states* of $C(S_N)$. Once this leap is made, to accepting that the elements of $M_p(S_N)$ can be studied as "permutations", it isn't so difficult to leap to quantum permutation groups $S_N^+$, where a state on an algebra $C(S_N^+)$ defining the quantum permutation group can be interpreted as a ``permutation'', *a quantum permutation*.

So, for a not-necessarily commutative $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra $C(\mathbb{X})$, I choose to interpret the state-space as the set of points:

1. Each self-adjoint $f\in C(\mathbb{X})$ is a real-valued random variable: given a state $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}(C(\mathbb{X}))$, output $f=\lambda$ occurs with probability $\varphi(p_\lambda)$, and $\mathbb{E}_\varphi(f)=\varphi(f)$.
2. $\mathcal{S}(C(\mathbb{X}))$ is compact Hausdorff.
3. Each such $f$ is continuous as a function $\mathcal{S}(C(\mathbb{X}))\to \mathbb{C}$: $$\lim_\lambda f(\varphi_\lambda)=f(\lim_\lambda \varphi_\lambda).$$
4. If we consider $\mathcal{S}(C(\mathbb{X}))$ as a set of "states", we can use elements of $C(\mathbb{X})$ to learn more and more about the state, but measurement involves state conditioning... and things are very different to classical case...

I am happy to explain further in comments, but perhaps if you are interested in this approach the above link might be the way to go.

Comment: JP, which topology do you introduce on ${\mathcal S}(A)$?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov weak*

Answer (score 7):

In the early days of noncommutative topology (the 60s and 70s) the idea that pure states are "points" was common. But I think Yemon's comments about there being too many pure states are well taken. I don't believe this idea is pursued much any more. I also think Yemon is correct in saying that one of the motivating ideas in noncommutative geometry is to deal with "spaces" that do not have points.

The following approach may or may not be helpful. In quantum mechanics the phase space of a system is modelled by a Hilbert space $H$, and the states of the system are the unit vectors modulo multiplication by scalars of modulus 1. In classical physics the phase space is just a set $X$, and we can describe a topology on $X$ by specifying a C${}^\ast$-subalgebra of $l^\infty(X)$. So we could say that we describe a "quantum topology" on $H$ by specifying a C${}^\ast$-subalgebra of $B(H)$, and the "points" of this topology are the unit vectors in $H$ modulo multiplication by scalars of modulus 1. This point of view is developed in my book *Mathematical Quantization*.

As I said, this may or may not be helpful for what you want to do.  I personally have gotten significant mileage out of it in my work on quantum graphs. (Specifically, [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.01259.pdf) and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.07394.pdf).) A quantum graph is a weak${}^\ast$-closed operator system $A \subseteq B(H)$, and if the unit vectors in $H$ are the "vertices" of the quantum graph then we can, e.g., define the degree of the vertex $v$ to be the dimension of $Av$. So in this setting the perspective I'm offering was very helpful.

Comment: I don't quite understand how you're answering my question. The notion of "noncommutative point" is rather vague, you say ? I.e. the definition of a noncommutative point depends on the formalism we follow ?

Comment: I'm really focused on a quantum space-time theory where space is quantized into "plank cells" by making it noncommutative (See intro of https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0109162 ). I was wondering whether these "plank cells" were equivalent to commutative points.

Comment: @Esmond do you want to elaborate on "captures the properties of the classical notion"? Which properties?

Comment: I mean that a point is a dimensionless object

Comment: @Esmond I am writing an answer but this comment is making me think twice. What do you mean by dimensionless object here?

Comment: Hello @JPMcCarthy , thank you for your investment ! I do not have a strong mathematical background, I am an autodidact. (I am now self-learning NCG for quantum gravity). For me, in "commutative mathematics", a point is basically a dimensionless object in the sense that we use it to define position. I've just edited my question

Comment: @Esmond define "position". I'm don't want to be negative: these terms you are using are far too vague. Maybe you should just say "point = element of a set".

Comment: @JPMcCarthy Yes, I think you're right. I will edit